Number of trials required to break even with a certain probability
I made a problem myself while reading an old econometrics book, but having a hard time solving it.

A single trial of a game is as follows.
 1. You pay L dollars to start the game.
 2. Toss a coin until you get heads. (The probability for heads and tails are equal.)
 3. You earn $2^m$ dollars, where $m$ is the number of tails before heads.
$I(n)$ is the income you get from $n$ trials.
 $I(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n (G_i - L)$,
  where $G_i$ is the money you earn from the $i$-th game.
If $L=10000$, what is the minimum value of $n$ for $P[I(n)\ge 0]\ge 1/2$?

The expected value of income from a single trial,
$$\begin{align}E[I(1)]&=\frac12(2^0-L)+\frac1{2^2}(2^1-L)+\frac1{2^3}(2^2-L)+ \ldots\\&=-L\left( \frac12+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{2^3} + \ldots\right)+\frac12+\frac12+ \ldots\\&=\infty\end{align}$$
However, $P[I(1)\ge0]=1/2^{15}+1/2^{16}+1/2^{17}+\ldots=1/2^{14}$
Intuitionally, since a single trial has an expectation of infinity, you can expect
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P[I(n)\ge0]=1$$
I ran a simulation, and got the expected result. The number of samples of $I(n)$ was $10000$.
(L = 10)
n      , P[I(n) >= 0]
      1, 0.0646
      2, 0.0787
      4, 0.0867
      8, 0.0984
     16, 0.1058
     32, 0.1206
     64, 0.1327
    128, 0.1350
    256, 0.1426
    512, 0.1583
   1024, 0.1781
   2048, 0.1962
   4096, 0.2266
   8192, 0.2529
  16384, 0.2858
  32768, 0.3344
  65536, 0.3909
 131072, 0.4659
 262144, 0.5602
 524288, 0.6633
1048576, 0.7953

(L = 20)
n      , P[I(n) >= 0]
      1, 0.0300
      2, 0.0354
      4, 0.0374
      8, 0.0378
     16, 0.0399
     32, 0.0438
     64, 0.0481
    128, 0.0537
    256, 0.0565
    512, 0.0566
   1024, 0.0611
   2048, 0.0646
   4096, 0.0650
   8192, 0.0632
  16384, 0.0654
  32768, 0.0647
  65536, 0.0690
 131072, 0.0755
 262144, 0.0728
 524288, 0.0754
1048576, 0.0773

You can see $P$ converges very slowly with only $L=20$, and we need to calculate $P$ for $L=10000$. It doesn't seem possible to get the result by simulation within reasonable time.
It seems best to get a simple algebraic solution for $f(n)=P[I(n)\ge0]$, but is it possible?
What are possible approaches to solve this problem?

This is known as the "St. Petersburg Lottery" or "St. Petersburg Paradox" and has been examined thoroughly. Here is a paper that deals with repetitions and their expected value: https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/50515/1/MPRA_paper_50515.pdf

From the simulations we can form an intuition that the correct $n$ must be very large. Fix $n$, then we can cap the game at $M=\lceil\log_2Ln\rceil$ initial tails because flipping that many initial tails is guaranteed to cancel all debts, leaving a positive income.
$I(n)$ is therefore the sum of $n$ iid random variables $X_i$ with finite support and hence finite expected value
$$E(X_i)=\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\frac{2^m-L}{2^{m+1}}+\frac{2^M-L}{2^M}=1-L+\frac M2$$
and by the central limit theorem we can approximate the least $n$ where $P(I(n)\ge0)\ge\frac12$ by the least $n$ where $E(X_i)\ge0$, i.e. $M=2(L-1)$ and
$$n=\left\lceil\frac{2^{2L-3}}L\right\rceil$$
For $L=10000$ this is obviously a physically impossible number.

Thanks for the answer! While I understood and agree until that $M=2(L-1)$, (and a bit confused in the last stage,) still, $M=2(L-1)$ seems to have some discrepancies with the simulation results (https://nopaste.net/result). I also double-checked the simulation code (https://nopaste.net/a.cpp).

Hmm maybe it's not a "discrepancy" because I think what you got as $n=\lceil...\rceil$ is more like $n\ge\lceil...\rceil$, and the simulation numbers do show that $n$ should be bigger than the $n$ calculated by your derivation. Also, could you elaborate a bit on how you solved $\lceil\log_2Ln\rceil\ge2(L-1)$ with $n$ on one side?

@xiver77 In order to have $\lceil\log_2Ln\rceil=2(L-1)$ with minimal $n$ we would have $\log_2Ln=2L-3+\delta$ where $\delta$ is some "small" positive number. We can just take powers of $2$ and divide to get the result; the ceiling rounds up, providing the $\delta$ needed.

I reiterate that it's only an estimate.
